# Google Docs proper sample code

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I downloaded Google docs client library from google docs api. But in that source all the examples are given for mac applications. I am facing problem while integrating this library for IOS platform. Could you please provide me library and sample which supports IOS

Thanks,
**Gopinath PUPPALA**

Answer (score 1):

There's a complete sample iOS application for the Drive API v2 in the Objective-C library:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FDriveSample